# How to fix undefined variable in PHP code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

This is my error when I click update button in view/tampil.php:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for Home::ubahdata()
Filename: controllers/Home.php
Line Number: 46
Backtrace:

File: A:\Sites\PHP_CI\CRUD\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 46
Function: _error_handler

File: A:\Sites\PHP_CI\CRUD\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: nohp
Filename: controllers/Home.php
Line Number: 52

Backtrace:

File: A:\Sites\PHP_CI\CRUD\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 52
Function: _error_handler

File: A:\Sites\PHP_CI\CRUD\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

When I click update button, it shows error undefined variable. where undefined variable does that mean? I think my error is not from undefined variable.

models/mahasiswa_model.php :

```
public function getUser($nohp)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('mahasiswa', array('nohp' => $nohp));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    public function ubah_model_data($user, $nohp)
    {
        $this->db->where('mahasiswa.nohp', $nohp);
        return $this->db->update('mahasiswa', $user);
    }
    public function ubah_model($nohp)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('mahasiswa', array('nohp' => $nohp));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

This is my code from controller/home.php :

```
public function ubahdata($nohp)
    {
        $user['nohp'] = $this->input->post('nohp');
        $user['nama'] = $this->input->post('nama');
        $user['alamat'] = $this->input->post('alamat');

        $query = $this->mahasiswa_model->ubah_model_data($user, $nohp);
    }
    public function ubah($nohp)
    {
        $data['mahasiswa'] = $this->mahasiswa_model->ubah_model($nohp);
        $this->load->view('home/tampil', $data);
    }
```

This is my code from view/tampil.php :

```
<form method="post" action="<?= base_url('home/ubahdata/'); ?>">
                     <?= $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
                     <div class="form-group row">
                         <div class="col-sm mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                             <label for="nohp">Nomer Handphone</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="nohp" name="nohp" placeholder="Masukkan Nomer Handphone" value="<?php echo $tampil->nohp; ?>">
                         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your method requires a parameter to be given whenever called,
that parameter is `$nohp` in your Home controller method `ubahdata`.So if you want to solve this problem you either have to pass that parameter when you call that method or remove it.I don't understand the purpose of this variable and looking at your HTML code you passing that variable via POST method so you don't need to pass that as parameter, you can just remove it. This just my understanding.

```
public function ubahdata()
    {
        $user['nohp'] = $this->input->post('nohp');
        $user['nama'] = $this->input->post('nama');
        $user['alamat'] = $this->input->post('alamat');

        $query = $this->mahasiswa_model->ubah_model_data($user,  $user['nohp']);
    }
    public function ubah($nohp)
    {
        $data['mahasiswa'] = $this->mahasiswa_model->ubah_model($nohp);
        $this->load->view('home/tampil', $data);
    }
```